# Is it possible for a react app to have multiple components with state?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning reactJS and following what I thought were best practices (state at lowest logical level).

My structure is:

- page with own inputs (own state)

  - card component (2 of these each with their own table)

    - table (own state for table inputs)

      - table row

        - table cell (with select input)
        - table cell (with text input)

I'm now trying to save my data to the server and it's occurring to me I have no way to save the state on the table. I may have to remove the table state and only have state at the highest level. Is it uncommon to have multiple states in the same app? If so, that means I have to write out the prop for the handler method for an onChange on an `input type="select"` in my table cell all the way down through page=>card=>table=>row=>cell? It seems like the props list will grow rather quickly with this pattern. I see this concern raised in some of the react documentation, but none of the suggestions seem to be a good fit. The example for `contexts` addresses a single item that may need to be accessed by many components not a series of props meant only for a few components that are just much further down the hierarchy.

Comment: you may need [redux](https://redux.js.org/), or [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) as an alternative option.

Comment: @Narro OP doesn't need either to manage state.

Comment: you might have to use `context API` -  https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Comment: Thanks just read that blog about the context API, based on his examples and those from the react docs it seems I should just move the state up. Is that what you're suggesting @Yatrix ?

Comment: My only other thought was to create a state prop in the `page` component `saveToServer` that is set to true when the user clicks save. It then passes that prop down to the `table` components that pick it up on `componentdidupdate` and save their states and flip it to `false` the parent wouldn't know if they both save successfully but I think thats ok. Does that sound like a bad pattern?